# deep nested routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have an application where the end goal is to have: a user has lists, a list has items, and a item has attachments. Obviously, I would not think about quad nested lists. Would it be any easier if I did something like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :lists 
end
```

and then

```
resources :items do
  resources :attachments
end
```

Could I then create my own routes and links which tie lists to items? Or would I still be facing the same issues when placing links_to's or when creating an attachment would I still need to work through user/id/list/id/item/id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good article, I have used this strategy ever since I read about it. I would never quad nest anything.

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/11-needless-deep-nesting

```
@post = Post.first
@post.each do |p|
   puts p.favorites
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a question regarding the article if you don't mind. The create action for favorites is /comments/:comment_id/favorites, but how would that associate the created favorite with the post, since its not /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/favorites

Comment: they are not directly associated. For example, you can get all the favorites from a post like the edit I did on the answer